# parsing text from an object tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

im creating a small amazon alexa skill called JokePro and i have made a website that i can directly upload jokes to. The jokes go into a txt file in the database and then are loaded to the crude page from there.

I am looking to randomly select lines from the joke file directly displayed to the page with an object tag

how would i go about scraping the text given by the object tag.

http://jokepro.dx.am

```
source = requests.get("http://jokepro.dx.am/")
bs4call = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
parsed = bs4call.find('pre') #ive replaced pre with object aswell
```

any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to load the text file described by `<object>` tag and then select random line from it:

```
import bs4
import requests
import random

url = "http://jokepro.dx.am/"

source = requests.get(url)
bs4call = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

obj = bs4call.find('object')

text = requests.get(url + obj['data']).text
# print(text) # <-- to print the textfile

print( random.choice(text.splitlines()) )
```

This prints (for example):

```
want to know a REALLY good joke? A high school student making this application in a week!
```

Comment: up vote and check! thanks a ton for spending time doing that. i was stuck on how i could get that data